# Using an ngModel for a column's select options

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I have created a table where a user selects a number from each cell. I'd like to add up all the values for each column and display the sum. I could do this by creating an `ngModel`for each `select` however this would result in a large number of `ngModels` and get confusing pretty fast.

Is there a better way of achieving this like using the same `ngModel` with different indexes or a similar method?

I have attached a [StackBlitz for this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swwges).

Answer (score 0):

Check my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9jput8). I just created an object with multiple indexes. Each index represent a select in the table. Then I use the `change`method the get the selected value and update my model.

```
  this.models = {
    'Alert':1,
    'Poised':1,
    'Patient':1,
    'Diligent':1,
    'Doing':1,
    'Childlike':1,
    'Experiencing':1,
    'Diversifying':1,
    'Reserved':1,
    'Serious':1,
 };

 valueChange(event,index) {
    this.models[index] = Number(event.target.value);
    console.log(this.models);
 }

 <select [innerHtml]="dropdown | safeHTML" (change)="valueChange($event,'Alert')"></select>
```